# Unfortunately 'app' has stopped working - No errors

Tags: android, debugging

My app has "Unfortunately had stopped working" yet in the debug there seems to be no errors. So far it is simply a few buttons and text with one button i have tried to connect to a new activity.
This is the console running,

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: Nexus_6_API_22 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\CALLUM\AndroidStudioProjects\Switch-game2\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/gameswitch.switch_game
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop gameswitch.switch_game
Launching application: gameswitch.switch_game/gameswitch.switch_game.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "gameswitch.switch_game/gameswitch.switch_game.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=gameswitch.switch_game/.MainActivity }
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8610', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8610', transport: 'socket'
```

and here is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    //new below here2
    <activity
        android:name=".GamePlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.AnotherActivity"/>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

and the next part

```
package gameswitch.switch_game;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //new below
    //Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Retro.ttf");
    //TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    //myTextView.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    //new below 2
    OnClickListener listnr = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent("GamePlay");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listnr);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

and the rest of the classes and co are standard strings and stuff.
Im pretty new to programming in Android Studio and im really not sure whats up since there are no underlines or errors i can see.

Since running again the error that appears is as follows

```
Process: gameswitch.switch_game, PID: 2774
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=GamePlay }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
        at gameswitch.switch_game.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Have you tried viewing your logcat?

Comment: In addition to that, does the app hang? If you're doing a lot of work on the UI thread when you start the other activity it could cause a crash.

Comment: Okay so ive ran it again and this time it has hung for little longer and i have a crash error, which is better. Yet still nothing is underlined as wrong in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent is wrong.
You should either explicty set the activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, GamePlay.class);
```

Or use the action you declare in your manifest

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("in.wptrafficanalyzer.AnotherActivity");
```

Your code failed because you launch an intent an action undeclared.

Comment: Ah yes I can see that now, makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.